# Left join 2 datatable

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 table:

Table A:

| id | Name | Age | Height |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Pauls | 22 | 170 |
| 02 | Sam | 20 | 175 |
| 03 | Mike | 20 | 175 |
| 04 | Jame | 23 | 180 |

id  Name    Age Height
01  Pauls   20  170
02  Sam 21  180

Table B:

| id | Height | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 175 | 23 |
| 02 | 190 | 21 |

The question here is how could I get this output by join 2 table A & B by id and get output table using Linq in C# OutputTable:

| id | Name | Age | Height |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Pauls | 23(value in table B) | 175 (value in table B) |
| 02 | Sam | 21(value in table B) | 190 (value in table B) |

Edit: I'm using these line of code but the output is not what I expected, I'm not used to work with linq so please tell me where's my mistake:

```
var results= from rowA in dA.AsEnumerable()
                                   join rowB in dB.AsEnumerable() on rowA[id] equals rowB[id] into dAB
                                   from subRight in dAB.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                   select  select rowLeft.ItemArray.Concat(rowRight.ItemArray).ToArray();
```

Comment: Not sure whether I have understood your question here, but it looks like the kind of data what you want as a result is already present in Table A (id,Name, Age, Height).
Then what else do you need? You can directly write a query to get records from Table A.

Comment: @AbhayDesai data in table B contain an update info for data in table A, My question is how can I join table B into table A by id

Comment: @AbhayDesai I had edited my question. Plz Help!!!

Comment: Why are you using a join for this?  This is not the case where you would us a join.  You just need to update Table A with Table B data by iteration

Comment: Can you try this and let me know what result are you getting??

var results = (from TableA in _context 
  join TableB in _context on TableA.id = TableB.id
  into values

  select value.id, value.Name, value.Age, value.Height);

return results;

Comment: @DJBurb this is just an example for my datatable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a solution:

```
 var results = from ta in tableA
               join tb in tableB on ta.id equals tb.id
               select new 
               {
                  ta.id,
                  ta.Name,
                  tb.Age,
                  tb.Height
               };
```

`results` will be your new data that you are expecting.

Comment: you can do a foreach loop and update the needed rows, but then again I thought about it and the join would be cleaner

Comment: see. Join is best option for large database

Comment: Can you explain *why* this achieves the desired result, for the sake of future readers?

Comment: @Tacoタコス like I said in the above answer. If you work in large database. Join  method is generally considered better, if only because it reduces the overhead of sending queries back and forth to the database.

Comment: @CalvinCreater not your comment; I'm requesting that the OP explain *why* their answer achieves the *desired* result.

Comment: @Tacoタコス I really don't understand your question. You wanted me to explain why their answer suitable for me right ?

Comment: @CalvinCreater no, I want the answerer to elaborate on their answer for future readers. What am I as a future reader supposed to learn from this answer, other than the fact that it solved your problem?